# Vintage 531 frame. Identify original make?

Tags: frames, vintage

[image: bike]I rescued this bike from the tip a couple of years back and rebuilt it (in the UK). I am curious to know what the original make might be? The original frame had been badly repainted so no makers name was visible, but the frame did have Reynolds 531 stickers. I have since had the frame sand blasted and powder coated. The Weinmann side pull brakes are original as far as I can tell. There's no serial number on the bottom bracket (or anywhere else). BREV CAMPAY
Stamped on rear dropout.
Just back from an autumnal ride, so a bit grimy!
Note:bottom bracket is not the original one!
[image: bike lugs]
[image: dropout][image: bottom bracket]
[image: front stem]

Comment: The key to identifying a bike like this is to find one or more frame details that are unique to a specific maker. The picture posted shows no unique details. A picture of the whole bike plus detail shots of the head tube, bottom bracket and rear drop outs might reveal a clue that will unlock the secret of the maker.

Comment: @DavidD Thanks! I've updated with more images!

Comment: I've seen those lugs on a Claud Butler from the 1960s before. But i think there is nothing unique about this construction, even though it is probably made by a skilled individual. There were hundreds of small makers building frames with similar lugs and dropouts during that era.

Comment: Absolutely nothing on the underside of the bottom bracket?

Comment: @shoover Nothing! As smooth as the proverbial babies behind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 1970's. Rear brake cable guides on top tube and bottle boss on down tube not used in 1970's due to belief that they weaken the tubing. More likely mid to late 1980's. The clamp on shifters narrows this down to earlier rather than later in 1980's.  Without the original bottom bracket you're most likely will never identify the maker.

Answer (score 3):

The **Reynolds 531** designation is sadly only the name of the steel tubing used in the frame, and has no relation to a frame builder.

Same goes for the dropouts which are stamped as **Campagnolo**.  In the 80's such parts were the lego-pieces many bike frame makers bought to use and don't help ID it at all.  Likewise for **Weinmann** brake calipers and **Suntour** accessories.

I'd suspect this bike had bolt-on axles originally with 630mm wheels.  The first photo shows the duller metal of aluminium rims, suggesting the wheels have been swapped for modern ones.  This helps with rim braking especially in the wet.

It looks like a loverly 80s bike and will go on for thousands of miles.  If you desire some kind of name on the side, get "Miguel" cut from white by someone with a vinyl cutter then stick it on the downtube.  Given the amount of work you've put into saving and salvaging it, you have a good claim to naming it anything you want.

Comment: Thanks. I am a veteran cyclists, so have ridden a few 531 frames in my time (Dawes, Claude Butler) but couldn't quite recognise the provenance of this particular frame. I think it belongs to the late 70's / early 80's but have still to find a perfect match. Thanks for the advice! This frame has manages 7,000 miles since I started restoring it back in 2020, so I hope for quite a few more!

Answer (score 1):

That might be a [Cilo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cilo). If so well done that was a find!

Cilo is the only bike maker I can find who does that decoration you can see on the butting. Doing an image search for [Cilo bicycle](https://www.google.com/search?q=cilo%20bicycle&tbm=isch) or some similar phrase will find you lots of pictures you can compare to your bicycle to see how close the match is.

For example I found [an article about a Cilo bicycle here](https://www.theproscloset.com/blogs/news/vintage-cilo-road-bike), and one of the pictures shows decoration on the butting that looks a lot like yours:

[image: Cilo decoration]

Comment: Yes that looks close, but I think it might be a bit up market. Also the back stays/down tube butting look quite different. Thanks for adding this. Looks like a great bike!